# What is difference between & and @ in SASS

Tags: sass

Can someone explain me the difference between **`&`** and **`@`** in SASS. `@extend` is used to share properties but isn't `&` doing the same? I'm confused. Thanks.

Comment: no they are different. `&` in sass has multiple meanings, if you use it before the selector it concatenator, glue... if you are selecting parent you declare `&` after your selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's good explanation of `&` and `@extend` in SASS: http://thesassway.com/intermediate/referencing-parent-selectors-using-ampersand
http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/a-better-clearfix-with-sass

Hope this is helpful!